# What does "where's waldo" mean in this context?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, meaning-in-context, neologisms

> The student thinks that he can *where's waldo* their way to the answer

Now, does it mean it's gonna be a cinch or a sisyphean task?

Again, if I add a little detail,

> The student thinks that he can *where's waldo* their way to the answer
>   by using the words in the passage.

The situation is that a student has to answer a question after reading a passage, trying to figure out whether the options match verbatim with some sentence in the passage.

Comment: This isn't really about English usage. [Where's Waldo](https://www.google.ca/search?q=where%27s+waldo&oq=where%27s+waldo&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2399j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) is a children's pay book where they search an image for a peculiarly dressed character.

Comment: [Judge for yourself, here](http://whereswaldo.com/).

Comment: 'Where's Waldo / Wally?' puzzles tend to be non-complex but not easy either. They require diligent searching rather than abstruse analysis. Perhaps this is a reference to students assuming that they won't have to dig into the deeper conceptual levels of say [Bloom's Taxonomy of Learning Domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom's_taxonomy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Where's Waldo" is a game where you have to scan a sketch of a crowd, looking for a particular person.

By using where's-waldo as a verb, I think the writer means the student is not going to *read* the passage, but just scan over it, looking for a few words that resemble the question.